# Custom validation in newform/editform using jquery

Tags: list, jquery, form, validation

I have an "Issue list" and I am writing some jquery code to validate some fields based on the status of the issue.
I am using `PreSaveAction()` function to make the validation, but I see that the fields which are set as required via the UI are not validated. I have to validate them as well. What is the best way to do custom validation in new/edit forms, but still retain validations of other fields which are already set as required via UI?

Comment: if you simply return false if there is a validation problem, or true if it is all good client-wise, the ootb validation should take care of the the remaining pre-existing validations

Answer (score 3):

When a field is set to required, then `Required Field` text is added to the `title` of the field. So, do something like this:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
if($('input[title="FieldName Required Field"]').val() == ''){
    alert('Please enter some value');
    return false;
}else{
   return true;
}
}
```