# Populating survey results into a new list

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey, survey-list

I have recently created a Survey on SharePoint 2010 (I do not have Designer installed). I would like to know if there is a way to have a "completed" survey populate into a new list.

For instance, the survey questions have information (when filled out) that will be similar to custom list columns that I am creating. So lets say I "add a new item" on the list, and I would like to populate information from response #15 (example).

Any insight on this would be great.

Comment: You need Designer( Workflows) or some pretty intense JavaScript code

Comment: You could make use of the "Default Values" here. Populate each column's setting to have a default value, however that would change for every user.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. But, it is tricky as you will need Nintex Workflow. Then you will use a combination of both Created By and a collection variable to get Survey item IDs. First thing to do is populate two collections in the same action: 1) User ID (ie. Created By) 2) IDs. Then you can tie the user who created the answers to the answers themselves through the item IDs.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to copy the responses from each Survey, once completed, to a second list. This is not too simple, even with Designer.

@Jeff is right that something like Nintex is probably the best way, but there is also a free way:

1. Create an HTML file that contains a `<script>` block with JavaScript code for creating a new list item in the second list at the moment the Save button is pressed on the Survey `NewForm.aspx`. The file should have roughly this structure:

   - First define a function for getting the response values from the form (here jQuery is helpful, but you can also use vanilla JS) ([See also](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148014/custom-validation-in-newform-editform-using-jquery))
   - Second define a function for creating a new list item using values passed in from the first function ([See also](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60005/add-new-item-to-list-in-javascript))
   - Third define a function called `PreSaveItem()` that contains calls to the first two functions ([See also](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/presaveitem-in-sharepoint-2013-newform-aspx-form/), [See also](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/what-is-the-difference-between-presaveaction-and-presaveitem-on-sharepoint-l))
2. Upload the HTML file to a location in SharePoint, and then edit your survey's `NewForm.aspx` page and [link to the HTML file from a Content Editor Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259616/referencing-javascript-library-in-content-editor-webpart).
3. Set permissions on the second list so that the same people who have access to respond to the survey also have access to add new items to it.

I have not tested this, but in theory this is what should happen: When the user submits his responses from NewForm.aspx, he will do so by clicking the "Save" button at the bottom of the form. This will trigger a call to `PreSaveItem()`, which will get values from the form, copy them to a new list item in the second list, and then save the response to the Survey list.