# Referencing javascript library in content editor webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, content-editor-web-part

So i have added content editor webpart in NewForm.aspx and reading the code to javascript file called **HideFields.ps1**. SO the script as below:

**HideFields.ps1**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

     $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
      var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

       //If the current User does belong to the group "Test Group"
        if (xml.search('Test Group') == -1)
         {
             $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Description")').parent().hide();

           }  
        }

     });

    });
    </script>
```

The above script work as expected if i reference jquery library and SPService library externally.

What it does not work if i have save the file in the same location of this javascript file (HideFields.ps1).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~siteCollection/Style Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
```

I tried also this one since the all the files existed in the same location

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If site url like http://sp, reference the library as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Style Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
```

If site url like http://sp/sites/team, reference the library as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/team/Style Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
```

Update：

My test result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tried this still however it is unable to load library

Comment: Check my test result.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 options -

- Place your files in some other custom libraries other than ***"Site Assets"*** or ***"Style Library"***, and then refer it in your HTML from there.
- Put your site in trusted locations in Internet Options settings of IE *(Settings > Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites > Sites > Add your site*